# Will the logs collected by k8s sidecar be lost?

Tags: kubernetes, sidecar

I use the sidecar method of k8s to collect logs. If I use emptydiry to mount, will the uncollected logs be lost when the pod is moved to another node?

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
 name: counter
spec:
 containers:
   - name: count
     image: busybox
     ...    
     volumeMounts:
       - name: varlog
         mountPath: /var/log
   - name: count-agent
     image: k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-gcp:1.30
     ...
     volumeMounts:
       - name: varlog
         mountPath: /var/log
       - name: config-volume
         mountPath: /etc/fluentd-config
 volumes:
   - name: varlog
     emptyDir: {}
   - name: config-volume
     configMap:
       name: fluentd-config
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this container `k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-gcp`?

Comment: This is a log agent container to collect logs. The completed code is here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/main/content/zh/examples/admin/logging/two-files-counter-pod-agent-sidecar.yaml @BernardHalas

Comment: Updating the link from @zzw 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/main/content/en/examples/admin/logging/two-files-counter-pod-agent-sidecar.yaml, which is referenced in the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#streaming-sidecar-container).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will lose the data. `emptyDir` is erased when a pod is removed (e.g. when it is evicted to another node).

The logs that you'd like to preserve should be printed to `stdout`; then collected and persisted by your logging subsystem in the cluster.

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir):

> An `emptyDir` volume is first created when a Pod is assigned to a node, and exists as long as that Pod is running on that node.

Comment: But most of my logs are stored in log files, and printed to `stdout` will collect files that I don’t want to collect

Comment: Sorry, I didn't fully understand what you meant. How about printing to `stdout` only the logs that you want to collect?